# jQuery hover(): mouseout does not fire when using overflow:auto (with scrollbars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery's `hover()` helper to attach some behavior to `<li>` elements in a `<ul>` with `max-height` and `overflow:auto` CSS properties.

When the height of the `<ul>` goes beyond `max-height` and the vertical scrollbar appears, hovering over the `<li>` elements triggers `mouseOver`, but if I move to the right to the scrollbar and start scrolling with the mouse, the `mouseOut` event never fires. (I have to hover back on the element and exit through some other direction to make `mouseOut` fire).

Is this a problem in jQuery or is it my specific situation that's triggering the bug?

Note: the `<li>` elements have `display:block` attached to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in Firefox only - jQuery bugtracker has an open ticket [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4469).

Comment: That ticket contains a good workaround. I've made some little fix (see my comment for the ticket), and all is working pretty well for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a browser specific problem?  It sounds like everything you want to happen could more efficiently be completed using the hover pseudo-class of CSS.  Also if the li elements are set to display block they will not have numbers or bullets associated with them in some browsers, because those browsers require the use of display:list-item to process elements with list item presentation.

Here is an example of hover from CSS:

ul:hover {height:10em;}

Comment: This is happening in Firefox 3. I don't need bullets so that's no problem. The :hover pseudo-class does not work in IE6 (which I still need to support).

Comment: hover does work in IE6 on anchor elements.  For an example how this is used to modify a list go to travelocity.com (the US or Canada version) and checkout the top navbar on the homepage.